# Error with Big query large data set query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am querying a large public data set in Big Query and when I select the entire table, I get an error saying the result is too big and I should enable the "Allow Large Results". I read through the documentation for this and followed the steps mentioned,

1. Select a destination table
2. Check " Allow Large results"

Despite doing this I get a very vague error that says "Required parameter Missing". I am not sure how to fix this error and what parameter is missing. I Wuld greatly appreciate if anyone who has encountered this error is able to provide some inputs

[Error page snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5ahm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out value for your destination table!  - `data-analyst-1326:null.tbl1`
The dataset value is null!

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks, you comments jelped me find the issue, I had not associated the destination with any data set. So, the first step is to create a data step and then associate the table with the data set. Now to create a data set, you need to provide the billing info. I did not want to do that because I am using big query to just answer an interview question. Nonetheless, I had to do it now and this is the resolution.